# Spring Hibernate One to many inserting null in Foreign key column with hibernate template

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have implemented one to many relationship (annotation) as follows:

// **User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email_id")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Address.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    ..... setters and getters
 }
```

// **Address Class**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="address")
    public class Address {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="add_id")
        private Integer addId;

        @Column(name="pin_code")
        private String pinCode;

        @Column(name="street")
        private String street;

        @Column(name="city")
        private String city;

        @Column(name="state")
        private String state;

        ... setters and getters

    }
```

The problem is that when I am saving **User** object (which also contains list of one **Address** object) with hibernate template, it is inserting **null** in foreign key column ("user_id") in **address table**.

It fires **2 insert statements** for both the tables but it is **NOT firing update statement** to update foreign key column

But when I use **SessionFactory** it works as expected (below is the code of session factory):

```
    SessionFactory factory = template.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();       

    try{
        //id = (Integer) template.save(user);
        id = (Integer) session.save(user);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        id = -1;
    }

    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

In above case it fire **2 insert and 1 update** to update foreign key column

Comment: where is the mapping for `user_id` in `Address` class

Comment: @Hema "user_id" is the new column name which is being referenced by "id" column of "Users" DTO

Comment: But then how come it is working in case of SessionFactory (SessionFactory case is mentioned above)

Comment: issue might be you may be not setting user_id before saving.. Please check tht once

Comment: ids are auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below mapping

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
@JsonIgnore 
private List<Address> addressList ;

//remaining fields and getter setters here
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="add_id")
    private Integer addId;


   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = true)
   private User user;

//remaining fields and getter setters here
}
```

Comment: I have already posted repository code (SessionFactory code) in the question itself

Comment: I am not getting any error, problem is still the same, foreign key column is being inserted by null value in address table

Comment: Yes as it is auto incremented tht might be the prob.. Once can u set manually one id and save the object and tell me