# Auto updating of the databases creates one-directional connection on the wrong side

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, model

The problem is that when i run the application hibernate creates a column user_id in the tahograph_cards table which i don't want and it doesn't create a column tahograph_card_id in the users table which I want to.
It's a OneToMany relationship.

Here are my files:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/getmydrivercard
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

User:

```
package com.getmydrivercard.getmydrivercard.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID userId;

    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String email;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<TahographCard> tahographCards;

    private String comments;

    protected User(){}

    public User(String username, String password, String email){
        setUsername(username);
        setPassword(password);
        setEmail(email);
        setComments(EMPTY_STRING);
        setTahographCards();
    }

   //getters and setters
}
```

TahographCard:

```
package com.getmydrivercard.getmydrivercard.models;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tahograph_cards")
public class TahographCard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID tahographCardId;

    @NotEmpty
    private Boolean isActive;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    protected TahographCard(){}

    public TahographCard(User user){
        setUser(user);
        setActive(true);
    }
    //getters and setters
  }
```

I tried with mappedBy and some other stuff I found on the Internet but still doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834029/6756805 you can check mapping in this answer,You have to add joinColumn in User entity also

Comment: already did that. doesn't work

Comment: `mappedBy = "users"`  change this and check once

Comment: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.getmydrivercard.getmydrivercard.models.TahographCard.users in com.getmydrivercard.getmydrivercard.models.User.tahographCards gives me that error

Comment: Ok got it..revert it

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name = "userId")` remove this and add `@JoinColumn(name = "tahographCardId")` in user

Comment: Why do you want tahograph_card_id  in user table? isnt the relation user oneToMany tahograph?

Comment: still not working

Comment: @Zeromus yes it is. For me is better to have the tahograph_card_id in the users table

Comment: @Zeromus why you think its not a good idea ?

Comment: It's kinda impossible to have it that way, how do you map a relationship with a column on the one side of the relation? what if you have one user and multiple TahographCard? what is the value off that column?

Comment: i will just have 10 rows with the same user in the users table ? Maybe i am talking nonsense, but I am still learning.

Comment: no you have one row for one user and 10 TahographCard rows. those TahographCard have each a column user_Id that map to which user they are connected

Comment: It's kinda the basic of relational database though, i would start from there before exploring hibernate

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation ! I was trying to solve the problem for 10 hours lol and didn't know mysql is working like that. Can you copy this as an answer so i can give you a green sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not the entities configuration but the database design.
You can't map a oneToMany relationship with a FK column on the one side.

For example if you have 2 Users and 4 TahographCard (2 for each user) normally it would look like this:

```
User
id name
1  Foo
2  Bar

Table
id user_id (fk)
1  1
2  1
2  2
2  2
```

The opposite with the TahographCardId on the User table is impossible